# How to make a start-up file launch a Command Line command on Start-Up?

Tags: vbscript, startup

So I've been working on a project, and I want the program to run a file that executes a command when I start-up my computer.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe" ""
Set oShell = Nothing
```

I do not know what to write in "" to make the start-up VBS file launch the Command Line and execute a command on start-up. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The following VBScript code opens a command window, changes to the path to C:\ , and executes the DIR command.

```
oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"

CMD /C    Run Command and then terminate

CMD /K    Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables
```

More information:
[CMD.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)